# Emacs: Terminal vs shell?

Tags: shell, emacs, terminal

I have been reading how to use a shell inside EMACS, along the way I found the concept of Terminal, which is an abstraction for the old physical devices which interacted with the shell.
But, nowadays, I really can't understand which are the advantages regarding its use, so, can you please point me out a couple of situations or examples where one should use it instead of the shell in Emacs?

Comment: The shell is very convenient, because usual emacs features (like isearch) work in it as expected.

Answer (score 19):

Running a term buffer is much closer to an actual terminal.  Here are a few differences:

- Shell mode provides very limited terminal emulation.  Programs that take advantage of the terminal's full-screen capabilities (e.g. `less`, `mtr`, `mutt`, `top`) won't work properly.  Terminal mode will generally handle these without any problem.
- In shell mode, emacs provides tab completion.  In terminal mode, the shell or command-line program provide it themselves.
- Shell mode buffers the input and sends it to the process on newline.  Terminal mode sends the characters to the running process immediately.
- Shell mode works like a regular buffer with the usual emacs key bindings.  Terminal mode doesn't intercept most control characters unless you explicitly put it into line mode.

Answer (score 4):

The shell is like another emacs buffer, so the same keys work in it which work in other buffers. It is not true for the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You can launch the console programs that clear the screen like `mc` in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Physical terminals *are* long obsolete, but the terminal emulators which replaced them are pretty important, and I would presume that most shells outside of Emacs are run within one, so it's not such a mysterious concept to use one within Emacs too.

It's only tangential to your question, but [The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) is an excellent article which you might find enlightening.